# Bijective restriction of the normalization morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities, normalization

Let $X$ be an integral separated scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$. Consider the normalization morphism $f:X'\rightarrow X$. Can we always find an affine open $U\subset X'$ such that $f|_U:U\rightarrow X$ is bijective on the underlying topological spaces?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{P}^1$. Though I do not know if what you say ever happens for $X$ non-affine. That might be an interesting question (or it might be me being stupid).

Comment: What if $f$ is already bijective? (e.g., $X$ a curve with a cusp).

Comment: @abx but do you know an example with $X$ non-affine, receiving a map from an affine scheme as described in the question? I am genuinely curious.

Comment: @schematic_boi: Take $X$ a cubic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ with an ordinary double point $s$, with normalization $f: \mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=s$, and $U=\mathbb{P}^1\smallsetminus\{0\} $.